# Loading content to the div using AJAX/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, frontend

I am a beginner in playing with jQuery/AJAX, my goal is to load content to the div below:

```html
<div id="blogcontentloaded">
    
</div>
```

I came up with .load and it worked, the page loads but it keeps refreshing and loads over and over.

```js
$(function loadBlog(e) {
    $('#blogcontentloaded').load('/blog/page1.html');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

I tried using e.preventDefault but it doesn't work for me. 
Also my goal is to do this without any buttons. When main page loads portion of the page that I want to load along with main page is going to be for updating the content in loaded element.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: As I said I am a beginner in coding, rather than voting down I could use some explaination what is wrong with code/post.

Comment: I have read this and vote up your question. Try to use my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the javascript `load` function. It may solve your problem. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) you can get some information about windows `load` and jQuery `ready` functions.

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
    $('#blogcontentloaded').load('/blog/page1.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the function in the 'ready' function and make sure that it is executed once:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#blogcontentloaded').load('/blog/page1.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the jQuery file on the top of other js files?

Add the jQuery.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#blogcontentloaded').load('/blog/page1.html');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
```